# Wizard with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I wabt to create a wizard for this form in a such way to give options of the second input based on the option of the first input

```
<form method="post" action="result.php">
<select>
    <option value="jean">jean</option>
    <option value="t-shirt">t-shirt</option>
</select>

<select>
    // if jean
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    // if t-shirt
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">See products</button>
</form>
```

For example if the user choose t-shirt, it will show him available colors of that item

Comment: Welcome to SO, Richad. SO requires that you should attempt to solve the problem yourself before asking a question, otherwise you're just asking us to do it for you. Here's [the help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question after you've tried yourself. Good luck! - (PS, you haven't actually asked a question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is probably what you're looking for:

```js
function updateColors(product) {
  document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = {
    "jean":    `<option value="black">Black</option>
                <option value="blue">Blue</option>`,
    "t-shirt": `<option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
                <option value="green">Green</option>`
  }[product];
}

window.onload = ()=>{updateColors("jean");}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="result.php">
<select onchange="updateColors(this.value)">
    <option value="jean" selected>jean</option>
    <option value="t-shirt">t-shirt</option>
</select>

<select id="color"></select>
<button type="submit">See products</button>
</form>
```

- The function `updateColors` takes a value, `product`, which is the value of the first selection box. It uses this to choose which colours to show; and then updates the HTML of that box.
- We call `updateColors` using the `onchange` event of the first select box. This event is fired whenever the user picks an item; so that the change happens immediately after. From this; I pass `this.value` - in this context, `this` refers to the first selection box, and `value` refers to the `value` attribute of the selected `<option>` tag.
- I have given the second selection box an id, `color`, so that we can easily reference it and change its contents.
- `document.getElementById("color")` references the second selection box; so we can change its properties.
- The `.innerHTML` property is used to change the HTML of a given DOM node (element on the page). By setting it, then we can change that element's HTML contents.
- Then; I use a dictionary (known as a *map* in other languages). This is a data structure that maps keys to values. Here, `jean` is a key, and then the HTML for the colors jeans come in is the value. Hence; we can get that HTML given the key. Likewise, `t-shirt` is another key; which has a different value.
- `[product]` is used to get the value for the given key. So if we pass in `jean`, it gives us back (as a string) the HTML value we set as the key. Then; that is set as the HTML code for the second selection box via `innerHTML`.
- `window.onload = ()=>{updateColors("jean");}` calls this function automatically when the page finishes loading. This is to ensure that the form makes sense before the user fills it out; as `jean` is selected by default so it makes sense to set the default content of the second selection box to be the colors for jeans.